# Try to correctly show image in tkinter into a method of a class

Tags: python, image, class, tkinter

I am writing a class that builds a canvas and positionate elements containing Title, Description and an Icon.
Everything works well except the part of showing the icon.

The class itself build the `canvas` and it have a method to add elements.

The problem comes when this function into the class.

```
def addElement(self, title='Element title', description='Element description' icon='*')
    if self.elementnumber != 10:
        self.elementnumber = self.elementnumber+1
    else:
        raise Exception("The maximum number of elements permitted is 10.")
    element=Frame(self.iconframe.interior, name=str(self.elementnumber))
    if icon != '*':
        self.iconimage = PhotoImage(file=icon)
        elementicon = Label(element, image=self.iconimage,name='icon')
    else:
        elementicon = Label(element, name='icon')
    elementtitle = Label(element, text=title, name='title')
    elementdescription = Label(element, text=description, name='description', wraplength=155,justify=LEFT)
```

So, when I call the function and put an icon, if I put `self.` to `iconimage`, I keep the reference and the image show correctly, but only the image for the last element.
I know that this is because `self.` is the reference for the main class and not for the element of the function, so this element keeps updating everytime I call the function, leaving only the last icon.

But, if I call the `PhotoImage` function without `self.`, anyone of the images shows it correctly.

So i don't know how to dow it to show the images correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.iconimage` has to be a list and for each new element, you have to manage the Index of that list.

Updating the `self.iconimage` to a list, try to use the `append` mehtod when adding New elements. Then, in `elementicon`, inform the new item appended of `self.iconimage` list.

Comment: That's it. For some reason, I don't think in use a list for this issue but it is the more logic answer to the problem.
Thank you so much!